# Assignment inside an expression?

Tags: c++

What is this code equivalent to?

```
int sec, mins, hours, days;
cin >> sec;
sec -=  (60 * 60 * 24) * (hours = sec / (60 * 60 * 24));
sec -=  (60 * 60) * (days = sec / (60 * 60));
sec -=  60 * (mins = sec / 60);
```

This code was written by my friend to calculate how many days, hours, minutes, seconds in an input entered in seconds. This seems so ambiguous to me.

```
sec -=  (60 * 60 * 24) * (hours = sec / (60 * 60 * 24));
```

Why does this line mean? I'm so confused by two assignment in a single expression. Is embedded assignment valid in standard c++? Regardless of the whole code.

Comment: It is. Is has the value that is assigned. It's usually frowned upon though, precisely because it makes the code hard to read.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_assignment As you can see the assignment operator has the default signature `T& T::operator =(const T2& b);` and it returns a reference to the assigned variable.  But what your friend wrote is certainly not nice code.

Comment: @HenriMenke Can you explain the line that I don't understand?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The line

```
sec -= (60 * 60 * 24) * (hours = sec / (60 * 60 * 24));
```

is equivalent to

```
hours = sec / (60 * 60 * 24);
sec -= (60 * 60 * 24) * hours;
```

---

The construction `(a = b)` is considered an *expression* that returns the value `b`. Here's a couple of examples of equivalent expressions:

```
5
4 + 1
2 * 2 + 1
2 * 2 + (a = 1)
```

So it all works out! That said... don't write code like this.

Comment: This is the right answer.
It actually answers the posted question.

Answer (score 0):

`=` operator receives two arguments, assigns the right one into left one, and returns the value assigned. Remeber, binary operator is just binary *function*.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int i;
    std::cout << (i = 42);
}
```

Output:

```
42
```

[(ideone)](https://ideone.com/CO5XM0)

Comment: Which operator is binary?

Comment: @MichaelJ.Harris you can check what operator is uniary, binary or ternary in your favorite C++ book or http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/expressions. The one requiring two arguments is binary operator.

Answer (score 0):

sec -=  (60 * 60 * 24) * (hours = sec / (60 * 60 * 24));

equals:

```
   days = sec / (60 * 60 * 24);
   days_secs = (60 * 60 * 24) * days;
   sec -= days_secs;
```

the variable "hours" is not so pretty,it should be "days".
Similarly, the variable "days" in

```
sec -=  (60 * 60) * (days = sec / (60 * 60));
```

should be "hours".

good luck.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the hours and days variables are mixed up, days should go first. I think substituting all those numbers with one variable helps:

```
#include <iostream>

#define secondsInaDay (60 * 60 * 24)
#define secondsInAnHour (60 * 60)
#define secondsInAMinute 60

int main() 
{
    int totalSeconds, mins, hours, days;
    cin >> totalSeconds;

    totalSeconds -= (secondsInaDay) * (days = totalSeconds / (secondsInaDay));
    // First divides the total seconds by the seconds in a day, giving the number of days.
    // Then subtracts the seconds that have been accounted as days on the left side.

    totalSeconds -= (secondsInAnHour) * (hours = totalSeconds / (secondsInAnHour));
    // First divides the remaining seconds by seconds in an hour, giving the number of hours.
    // Then subtracts the seconds that have been accounted for as hours.

    totalSeconds -= secondsInAMinute * (mins = totalSeconds / secondsInAMinute);
    // First divides the remaining seconds by seconds in a minute to give the number of minutes
    // Then subtracts the seconds that have been accounted for as minutes.

    int seconds = totalSeconds;
    // Any remaining seconds are added to seconds

    return 0;
}
```